# OS selection bash middlescript in $PATH

Tags: shell-script

Together with `~/.ssh`, I sync `~/bin` across systems, the script to sync the files also sets up and maintains `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` with references to some files to be `source`d in `~/bin` so bash is always the same regardless of system.

One thing I haven't managed to do, is about this multi-platform tool that comes with a few supporting files for each OS, I written OS-detection scripts a few times before, that, I can manage; but the resource files of each version of the tool not only conflict but having them in a flattened structured, and thus all in `$PATH`, would definitely clutter the output <kbd>⇥</kbd>-completing commands.

[image]

Since I want to call this tool from any directory using relative file paths, like you would with any other utility in the path, it complicates how to pass down the information to the environment of the subshell where the tool would run; as I'd need to also add the subdirectories in `/bin`, which are also relative (though `$HOME` is of huge help) because of the synced nature of the directory.

How can I do this? After the OS evaluation, what would be the next step to take?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to something we can reproduce. It is very hard to understand what you need. Do you just want a script that sets up a different `PATH` on different systems? Can you show us what you have so far so we have something to work with?